# some Matlab ctrl shortcuts don't work in Linux

Tags: linux, matlab, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm working with Matlab R2015a on Linux (Fedora OS).
The Matlab Editor shortcuts are defined as the default Windows shortcuts.
Some of them work OK (for example: ctrl+c , ctrl+s, ctrl+o) but some of them don't do anything (ctrl+F3 for searching the next appearance of a selection (while strangely Ctrl+Shift+F3 works OK for searching previous appearance of a selection), ctrl+d for opening a script/function..).
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on `Ubuntu`:

Go to

```
MATLAB > Preferences > Keyboard > shortcuts
```

There you can either

1- choose :

**Windows default**

or

2- customize the specific key combinations yourself.

[image]

Comment: Shortcuts are defined properly there - but they simply don't work.